# Compile Angular template received as HTML

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an app that pulls in HTML asynchronously and displays it. But the HTML has within it an Angular directive. The problem is that the directive is not being compiled. How can I force this to happen?

HTML:

```
<div>
    Outer html
    <angular-directive></angular-directive>
</div>
```

Content of angularDirective:

```
    <div>Test Content</div>
```

But this doesn't display the content of the angularDiretive, only the tag.

Comment: Use $compile service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html

> When should I use $compile?
>
> Truthfully? Almost never. It's going to be pretty rare that you should have to compile some HTML and process it as a view. Generally, you can just use directives that already exist to do whatever it is you think you need to do with $compile. But I suppose there are some edge cases where you may want to use it. Such as creating a completely custom repeater or something like that.

But if you REALLY need it, then do this

```
var html = '<h1>my custom template loaded from whatever location</h1>'
// insert html string into element
element.html(html);
// compile
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

I've just the $compile service only once, I am working in Angular for more than 2 years already ...

Answer (score 0):

Inject [**$compile**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service into your directive. And pass the html element to `$compile` as a parameter. It will compile the html and the it will be visible in the view.